# Authenticate proxy server (ccproxy) in headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome-headless, chromedp

I'm using [golang chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) as headless webdriver and [ccproxy](https://www.youngzsoft.net/) as proxy server, according to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) i'm set credentials headers but chrome also show basic authentication popup.

chromeDP (set headers):

```
func (c *Browser) setHeaders() chromedp.Tasks {
    authData := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(c.Proxy.User + ":" + c.Proxy.Password))
    headers := map[string]interface{}{
        "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic " + authData,
    }

    return chromedp.Tasks{
        network.Enable(),
        network.SetExtraHTTPHeaders(headers),
    }
}
```

...
apply:

```
if err := chromedp.Run(c.ctx,
    c.setHeaders(),
    chromedp.Navigate(c.NavigationUrl),
    chromedp.Reload(),
); err != nil {
    log.Println("error# ", err)
    return c
}
```

Comment: Where is the question? :)

Comment: @Marcin ...`i'm set credentials headers but chrome also show basic authentication popup` :))

i think chrome not accept the headers or not send to proxy server or ccproxy not authorize with this headers!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `examples` repo which has an example of proxy authentication: https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/proxy/main.go.